# How to use different properties of a Object type jmeter variable?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a jmeter variable suppose `${employee}` whose value is `{empid:"E101",empname:"XYZ",empcity:"Chennai"}`.

I want to use this variable in different Http calls for e.g.

```
demo.exmaplecode.com?Id=${employee}.empid
demo.exmaplecode.com?Name=${employee}.empmname
demo.exmaplecode.com?City=${employee}.empcity
```

I am not able to extract values by using "." operator.
Please suggest extracting values from an object type variable in jmeter.

Comment: Please add some code example

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this fairly easily using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31), the relevant expressions would be something like:

- `${__groovy((new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('employee'))).empid,)}`
- `${__groovy((new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('employee'))).empname,)}`
- `${__groovy((new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('employee'))).empcity,)}`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Parse JSON]

More information: [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and choose radio button `JMeter Variable` and enter variable name

to get for example empid use the following setting:

```
Variable Names: empid  (your new variable name for id)

JSON Path Expressions: $.empid

Match No.: 1
```